# Which Android technology is better suitable for this requirements?

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager, android-workmanager, android-jobscheduler

Conditions:

1) The user can create a schedule for each week day.

2) The user only defines the start time of the job.

3) From now a then, the job will be executed each day at the time scheduled in condition 1 and 2

4) The job is executed allways (never enqueued), even with low battery.

Question:
Which is better for this?

- AlarmManager
- JobSchedule
- WorkManager
- A Service in foreground
- A Service in background

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If exact timing is a requirement, you'll need to use AlarmManager and manage re-setting your alarms when the device restarts or your app is force stopped.  None of the others are currently suited to running work at an exact time.  See [this guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/#choosing_the_right_solution_for_your_work) from the Android Developers site for additional guidance on the differences between these solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Your requirement (4) is challenging to meet I would say. With the introduction of Doze mode and various other battery saving measures added to later versions of Android, you will not always have full control of it.

If you are flexible on that, your best bet is:

```
WorkManager
```

It is the best suited construct for your requirements and for any such requirements.
If you read the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/#workmanager), it states that WorkManager leverages the other technologies in a way that is best suited to specific versions of Android.

It has APIs to let you achieve all the other tasks that fall in your requirements and on the way handles backwards compatibility well.

Comment: Assuming exact timing is important, WorkManager is the wrong fit here.  From the page you linked: "For work that is deferrable and expected to run even if your device or application restarts, use WorkManager. ... If you need to run a job at a precise time, use AlarmManager."  This work "will be executed each day at the time scheduled" and thus does not sound deferrable.

Comment: Good point. Yes, if precise timing is a constraint then AlarmManager is the option.